# ioctl bug returning -1 EINVAL in SPI transfer function

Tags: c++, c, linux, spi, ioctl

Not sure if this is C related or something to do with the linux kernel. I'm using an SPI library for Beaglebone called BlackLib, and it has an SPI transfer function.

For some reason it wouldn't work when I first tried it. I played around with it for days and accidentally got it working when I had declared two random arrays inside the **function** itself, even though it has zero effect. If i remove them, the function breaks again at the ioctl line.

So for example if I call:

```
uint8_t writeBuffer[2] = {0x00, 0x01};
uint8_t readBuffer[2] = {0,0};
transfer(writeBuffer, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), 10, 0)
```

On the **function**:

```
bool   BlackSPI::transfer(uint8_t *writeBuffer, uint8_t *readBuffer, size_t bufferSize, uint16_t wait_us, uint16_t pad)
{  
    uint8_t tempReadBuffer[ bufferSize ];
    memset( tempReadBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

    spi_ioc_transfer package;

    package.tx_buf          = (unsigned long)writeBuffer;
    package.rx_buf          = (unsigned long)tempReadBuffer;
    package.len             = bufferSize;
    package.delay_usecs     = wait_us;
    package.speed_hz        = 5000000; //uint32_t
    package.bits_per_word   = 8; //uint8_t
    package.pad             = pad;

    // IF I DELETE THESE TWO DECLARATIONS, SPI transfer will fail. 
    // I have no idea why.. maybe causing a specific delay in the code that lets spi work, or overwriting old memory addresses that c++ attemps to access?
    uint8_t arr[4] = {0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
    uint8_t arrr[4] = {0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};

    //ioctl call
    if( ::ioctl(this->spiFD, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &package) >= 0){
        memcpy(readBuffer, tempReadBuffer, bufferSize+pad);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It returns true (worked). But if i comment out the 2 arrays like so

```
//uint8_t arr[4] = {0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
//uint8_t arrr[4] = {0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};
```

the function returns false (didn't work), and the `strace` output contains:

```
ioctl(4, 0x40206b00, 0xbe899b80)        = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

This is causing problems in my code because if i make some changes in other linked libraries or even my own code, it causes this SPI transfer function to stop working.

This is beyond my knowledge of how C/C++ code interacts with the linux OS, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The symptoms you have described are classic results of undefined behaviour. Which can be caused by many things such as memory corruption, using uninitialised variables, etc. That being the case, it is unlikely we can spot  the problem unless a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is provided - the root cause may not even be in the code snippet you have shown.

Comment: For example, we don't know what the value of `bufferSize` is. It could be so large that the stack overflows. That's just an example to illustrate how it is often impossible to diagnose problems with incomplete code.

Comment: @kaylum I've added an example call to the function. I am open to trying out debugging suggestions too.

Comment: @AlexF Hi, Sorry mate I've corrected this.

Comment: That's still not a minimal reproducible example. Please read the link to understand what that is. You may think it's not important but as I explained, the problem may not be where you think it is and providing selective snippets of code is not enough and may just waste people's time. You need to provide complete code that reproduces the problem. Ideally code that someone else can compile but even if not it must be complete code that you have compiled and reproduced the problem with.

Comment: @kaylum Nah im good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. C/C++ doesn't guarantee that all elements of arrays/structs are initialized to 0 if you don't initialize them to anything. Using `memset` and `memcpy` might not guarantee this either. Thus the `ioctl` call was returning errors since the `package` struct contained incorrect values in some members.

I had to initialize spi_ioc_transfer struct `package` and `tempReadBuffer` to zeros like so to make sure I was not getting any nasty surprises:

```
spi_ioc_transfer package = {};
uint8_t tempReadBuffer[ bufferSize ] = {};
```